# Twilio : Twilio was unable to parse the provided XML Document

Tags: android, twilio

i'm trying to use programming voice in android application using this example [link](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android).

I hosted the python file and everything and and I changed the 'twiMLParams' in the quickstart code

```
 twiMLParams.put("To", "oussema");
 twiMLParams.put("From", "me");
 twiMLParams.put("Caller", "oussema");
 twiMLParams.put("Called", "me");
 activeCall = Voice.call(VoiceChat.this, TWILIO_ACCESS_TOKEN, twiMLParams, callListener);
```

I got this error : Twilio was unable to parse the provided XML Document. 
What's I'm doing wrong here ? the problem is server side not client,

Comment: Can you check the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger) and find the XML that couldn't be parsed. If you can share that XML we can see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solved] : 
Thanks to Twilio support

android code :

```
 twiMLParams.put("From:","leme" );
 twiMLParams.put("To:", "oussema");
 activeCall = Voice.call(VoiceChat.this, TWILIO_ACCESS_TOKEN, twiMLParams, callListener);
```

Python code :

```
IDENTITY = request.values.get('To:', None)
CALLER_ID = request.values.get('From:', None)
client = Client(api_key, api_key_secret, account_sid)
return str('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Dial><Client>' + IDENTITY + '</Client></Dial></Response>')
```